# Configure WiFi roaming for Gnome Network Manager

Tags: 16.04, wireless, gnome, network-manager

Is it possible to change/configure the WiFi roaming strategy for [Gnome Network Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager)?
In general I would like to be able to configure how sticky it should be to connected access points (APs) and possibly give it a hint of which AP it should currently use.

For handling (wifi) connections, I'm using NetworkManager on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It "sticks" to one network until it looses signal. What exactly are you trying to change here?

Comment: We have seen it sticking to an access point (ap) with very low signal while another ap with significant better signal was available. We have also seen it jump ap while the signal strength was increasing.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution is late and temporary, one method would be to set:

```
wpa_cli -p /run/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 set_network 0 bgscan '"simple:A:B:C"'
```

where K is how long you want to check after it has reached a certain threshold lower than `B` (this is based off of signal level so something like -60 would work), if anything is better than this threshold it'll search every 60 seconds instead.

So lets say you wanted your wireless card to search every 5 seconds if it has a signal level of -70, but if the current signal is better than that, search every 120 seconds, you would do the following:

```
wpa_cli -p /run/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 set_network 0 bgscan '"simple:5:-70:120"'
```

I hope this helps, and hopefully someone can give a more efficient answer.